# Compare multiple value in a dictionary and get bigger value key

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I compare that 2 keys with the highest length of the value?
I wanna found the highest key name which has a bigger length.

```py
{
'UFTBUSD': ['Hammer', 'Belthold', 'Doji', 'Three Outside', 'Hanging Man', 'Closing Marubozu', 'Dragonfly Doji', 'Engulfing Pattern', 'Gravestone Doji', 'Harami Pattern'], 
'ANCBUSD': ['Belthold', 'Doji', 'Three Outside', 'Shooting Star', 'Closing Marubozu', 'Engulfing Pattern', 'Harami Pattern']
}
```

Comment: If I understand you right, you want a key where its value has biggest length? In this example `UFTBUSD` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
thisdict = {
    'UFTBUSD': ['Hammer', 'Belthold', 'Doji', 'Three Outside', 'Hanging Man', 'Closing Marubozu', 'Dragonfly Doji', 'Engulfing Pattern', 'Gravestone Doji', 'Harami Pattern'], 
    'ANCBUSD': ['Belthold', 'Doji', 'Three Outside', 'Shooting Star', 'Closing Marubozu', 'Engulfing Pattern', 'Harami Pattern']
    }

def find_largest_key(pattern_with_symbol):
   count = 0
   for key, value in pattern_with_symbol.items():
      if len(value) > count:
         count = len(value)
         long_key = key
   return long_key

print(find_largest_key(this_dict))
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
thisdict = {
    'UFTBUSD': ['Hammer', 'Belthold', 'Doji', 'Three Outside', 'Hanging Man', 'Closing Marubozu', 'Dragonfly Doji', 'Engulfing Pattern', 'Gravestone Doji', 'Harami Pattern'], 
    'ANCBUSD': ['Belthold', 'Doji', 'Three Outside', 'Shooting Star', 'Closing Marubozu', 'Engulfing Pattern', 'Harami Pattern']
    }
    
def find_longest_key(mydict):
    count_value = 0
    for x, y in mydict.items():
      for value in y:
        if len(value) > count_value:
            count_value  = len(value)
            print(len(value))
            longest_value = value
            longest_values_key = x
    print(longest_value)
    print(longest_values_key)
    return longest_values_key
    
    
find_longest_key(thisdict)
```

Comment: Thanks but If i add another bigger length key in this dictionary then it's not working.https://prnt.sc/vUHa4LU2k2Wj

Comment: anyway i solve it but thanks for your help